AWS function invocation error cannot find module 'request'
I'm trying to create a Lambda function on AWS that processes some images, but there is an error when it's invoked.
I'm trying to create a function that processes some images but it doesn't work. I added the code to the js files.
handler.js:
'use strict'

const request = require('request')
const urlParser = require('url')
const URLSearchParams = require('url').URLSearchParams
const shortid = require('shortid')
const asnc = require('async')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({region: process.env.REGION})
const images = require('./images')()

function writeStatus (url, domain, results) {
  let parsed = urlParser.parse(url)
  parsed.hostname = domain
  parsed.host = domain
  const statFile = {
    url: urlParser.format(parsed),
    stat: 'downloaded',
    downloadResults: results
  }

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    s3.putObject({Bucket: process.env.BUCKET, Key: domain + '/status.json', Body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(statFile, null, 2), 'utf8')}, (err, data) => {
      resolve({stat: err || 'ok'})
    })
  })
}


function createUniqueDomain (url) {
  const parsed = urlParser.parse(url)
  const sp = new URLSearchParams(parsed.search)
  let domain


  if (sp.get('q')) {
    domain = sp.get('q') + '.' + parsed.hostname
  } else {
    domain = shortid.generate() + '.' + parsed.hostname
  }
  domain = domain.replace(/ /g, '')
  return domain.toLowerCase()
}


function crawl (domain, url, context) {
  console.log('crawling: ' + url)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    request(url, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) { return resolve({statusCode: 500, body: err}) }
      images.parseImageUrls(body, url).then(urls => {
        images.fetchImages(urls, domain).then(results => {
          writeStatus(url, domain, results).then(result => {
            resolve({statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(result)})
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
}


function queueAnalysis (domain, url, context) {
  let accountId = process.env.ACCOUNTID
  if (!accountId) {
    accountId = context.invokedFunctionArn.split(':')[4]
  }
  let queueUrl = `https://sqs.${process.env.REGION}.amazonaws.com/${accountId}/${process.env.ANALYSIS_QUEUE}`

  let params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify({action: 'analyze', msg: {domain: domain}}),
    QueueUrl: queueUrl
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    sqs.sendMessage(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) { console.log('QUEUE ERROR: ' + err); return resolve({statusCode: 500, body: err}) }
      console.log('queued analysis: ' + queueUrl)
      resolve({statusCode: 200, body: {queue: queueUrl, msgId: data.MessageId}})
    })
  })
}


module.exports.crawlImages = function (event, context, cb) {
  asnc.eachSeries(event.Records, (record, asnCb) => {
    let { body } = record

    try {
      body = JSON.parse(body)
    } catch (exp) {
      return asnCb('message parse error: ' + record)
    }

    if (body.action === 'download' && body.msg && body.msg.url) {
      const udomain = createUniqueDomain(body.msg.url)
      crawl(udomain, body.msg.url, context).then(result => {
        queueAnalysis(udomain, body.msg.url, context).then(result => {
          asnCb(null, result)
        })
      })
    } else {
      asnCb('malformed message')
    }
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err) }
    cb()
  })
}



images.js:
'use strict'

const request = require('request')
const htmlparser = require('htmlparser2')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
const uuid = require('uuid/v1')

module.exports = function () {

  function parseImageUrls (html, url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let urls = []
      const parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
        onopentag: function (name, attribs) {
          if (name === 'img' && attribs && attribs.src) {
            if (/^data:image/i.test(attribs.src)) {
              urls.push({url: attribs.src, id: attribs.id})
            } else if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(attribs.src)) {
              if (attribs.src[0] === '/' || url[url.length - 1] === '/') {
                urls.push({url: url + attribs.src, id: attribs.id})
              } else {
                urls.push({url: url + '/' + attribs.src, id: attribs.id})
              }
            } else {
              urls.push({url: attribs.src, id: attribs.id})
            }
          }
        },
        onend: function () {
          resolve(urls)
        }
      }, {decodeEntities: true})
      parser.write(html)
      parser.end()
    })
  }


  function fetchImage (imageUrl, id, domain) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('fetching: ' + imageUrl)
      request.head(imageUrl, (err, response, body) => {
        console.log('fetching: ' + response)
        if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) { return resolve({url: imageUrl, stat: response.statusCode, err: err}) }

        request({url: imageUrl, encoding: null}, (err, response, buffer) => {
          console.log('fetching: ' + response.statusCode)
          if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) { return resolve({url: imageUrl, stat: response.statusCode, err: err}) }

          const fileName = uuid()
          s3.putObject({Bucket: process.env.BUCKET, Key: domain + '/' + fileName, Body: buffer}, (err, data) => {
            console.log('writing: ' + imageUrl)
            resolve({url: imageUrl, stat: err || 'ok'})
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }


  function decodeImage (imageUrl, id, domain) {
    const spl = imageUrl.split(',')
    const data = spl[1]

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let type = /data:image\/(.+);base64/i.exec(spl[0])
      if (type) {
        type = type[1]
        const b = Buffer.from(data, 'base64')

        const fileName = uuid()
        s3.putObject({Bucket: process.env.BUCKET, Key: domain + '/' + fileName, Body: b}, (err, data) => {
          resolve({url: imageUrl, stat: err || 'ok'})
        })
      } else {
        resolve({url: imageUrl, stat: 'unknonwn type'})
      }
    })
  }


  function fetchImages (images, domain) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let promises = []
      images.forEach(image => {
        if (/^data:image/i.test(image.url)) {
          promises.push(decodeImage(image.url, image.id, domain))
        } else {
          promises.push(fetchImage(image.url, image.id, domain))
        }
      })
      Promise.all(promises).then(values => { resolve(values) })
    })
  }


  return {
    fetchImages,
    parseImageUrls
  }
}



When the function is invoked I get this error message:
2024-06-02T15:23:47.691Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'request'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handler.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'request'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/handler.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}

